# Primefaces Command button hangs IE 9 browser

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml, internet-explorer-9, commandbutton

I've been working with JSF and primefaces for past 2 years. I'm facing an issue with the Primefaces CommandButton while using `<p:commandButton>` with `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` specifically in IE 9 (works fine in IE 8, IE 10 and IE 11).

Below is the code I'm using

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="btn-primary-starr btn-starr right-align-only" value="#{traveldictionary['travel.tile.traveler.Continuebutton']}" update=":tabContent :createQuotePage" process=":tabContent">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{DeleteTravelerDetailManagedBean.ajaxMap['DeleteNoteMessage']}"
          value="false" />
<f:setPropertyActionListener
      target="#{headerApplicationManagedBean.ajaxMap['Object::Tab::Active']}"
      value="payment">
</f:setPropertyActionListener>
<f:setPropertyActionListener
      target="#{headerApplicationManagedBean.ajaxMap['Object::Tab::GetQuotes']}"
      value="show">
</f:setPropertyActionListener> 
<f:setPropertyActionListener
      target="#{headerApplicationManagedBean.ajaxMap['Object::Tab::Save::travelerinformation']}"
      value="true">
</f:setPropertyActionListener> 
</p:commandButton>
```

When this command button is clicked the IE 9 browser force closes

[image]

But works on all other browsers including IE 8, IE 10 and IE 11. I did some research to find out if there were any known issues with IE 9 and Primefaces but no luck.

It would be really helpful if someone could shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.